# A user create a record in FeedItem using lwc (experiencecloud) but he cannot able to view the records in Exp cloud site. but admin can, how solve this

Tags: feeditem

A user can create a record in FeedItem using lwc but he cannot able to view the records in Experiencecloud site. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason why the user can create a record in **FeedItem** using **LWC** but cannot view the records in **Experience Cloud** site is that the feed item visibility is not set to `AllUsers` or `ExternalUsers`.

By default, the feed item **[visibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)** is set to `InternalUsers`, which means that only internal users can see the feed item. To make the feed item visible to **Experience Cloud** site users, the **visibility** field of the feed item record must be changed to `AllUsers`.

Visibility can have the following values:

- **AllUsers**: The feed item is available to all users who have permission to see the feed item.
- **InternalUsers**:The feed item is available to internal users only.

Note the following exceptions for Visibility:

- For record posts, Visibility is set to InternalUsers for all internal users by default.
- External users can set Visibility only to AllUsers.
  Visibility can be updated on record posts.
- The Update property is supported only for feed items posted on records.

Comment: The visibility is set to all users,but the records are not visible still.